# How can I make the font-family and font-size in my SharePoint List all the same?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, css, sharepoint-list

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 where the fonts are all over the place: Verdana, Arial, New Times Roman, 12pt, 8pt, etc.  How do I set a standardized format?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your site master page setting page, find out what is the the **css file** is used in the site. Download that css file. Locate the below css class in that file:

```
<style>

  /* Set font sizes on Header and Cells    */

.ms-vh2, .ms-vh
{ 

font-size:19pt;}

.ms-vb2, .ms-vb
{ font-size:19pt;} 

.ms-rtestate-field
{ 
/*font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;*/
font-size:19pt;
line-height: none} 

</style>
```

Now, adjust your font size and font family. Finally, apply back this modified css file to the site.

Source :

[Change default list Font Size SharePoint 2013](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/change-default-list-font-size-sharepoint-2013/m-p/166871)

Answer (score 1):

Add the CSS Style below in a Script Editor Web Part in the List View page or add into master page， List Header 12pt, List Item 8pt:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-vh2, .ms-vh
{ 

font-size:12pt;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Verdana, Arial;
}

.ms-vb2, .ms-vb

{ font-size:8pt;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Verdana, Arial;

} 


</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Can't believe how easy that was.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I guess I spoke too soon.  It looks like the text entry is still Times New Roman.  I placed the css in a script editor

Comment: Times New Roman is set in the CSS, if you want other font style, you can set in CSS.
Refer the font style list here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-font-families/